# Ninja framework with GAE: accessing the google app engine development console

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ninjaframework

When using GAE through the Ninja framework I cannot seem to access the development console usually located at `http:localhost:8080/_ah/admin`.
This is the console that allows you to view the datastore, logs, etc.  How could I access it?

Comment: At least in python the admin server's port may change depending on the app's structure. It's displayed in the run log when devserver starts. Try using the displayed URL instead of `http:localhost:8080`.

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu  Thanks - but I checked the displayed URL and it is still the standard localhost:8080/_ah/admin. Though it appears that ninja is catching it and displaying its own custom route not found page.

Comment: Then you have ninja config work ahead of you :)

Comment: @Dan Cornilescu great times, think I solved it, I'll post an answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this by looking at the sample  ninja-appengine application presented in the ninja-appengine github readme.  I noticed that their sample app did not suffer from the same issue and it is due to the inclusion of the conf/ServletModule.java file which I was missing.  The code below does two things:

it inserts an Objectify Filter through Java code rather than requiring that the objectify filter be included via the web.xml.

Secondly it makes the _ah/admin paths visible when running in a dev environment.  Note, I have just copied in the code given in the sample ninja-appengine web application:

package conf;

import ninja.servlet.NinjaServletDispatcher;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter;

public class ServletModule extends com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule {

```
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {

    bind(NinjaServletDispatcher.class).asEagerSingleton();

    // Clean objectify instances with that filter:
    bind(ObjectifyFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
    filter("/*").through(ObjectifyFilter.class);

    if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {

        serve("/*").with(NinjaServletDispatcher.class);

    } else {
        // do not serve admin stuff like _ah and so on...
        // allows to call /_ah/admin and so on
        serveRegex("/(?!_ah).*").with(NinjaServletDispatcher.class);
    }

}
```

}